# Can a text editor be built from scratch in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, editor

I am aware that Javascript WYSIWYG editors use the inbuilt editor mode of the browser to function, but that comes up with various problems and issues.

Can an editor be built from scratch in JS, something like what Buzzword people have done with flash/flex? I came across [this blog post](http://manishjethani.com/blog/2008/04/13/how-does-buzzword-work/) recently and I am just wondering if this can be built (atleast to a moderate extent) using Javascript?

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by "from scratch". [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/) provides a pretty good text editor in JS. Is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it and it is not very difficult.
But before reinventing the wheel please take a look at all the existing ones.
Many of them are really very well written and open source.

Answer (score 0):

Almost anything can be done with JavaScript. You have the basic building tools right there - you can intercept all mouse events and nearly all keyboard events. You can use a GIF animation for simulating the caret. The trickier part might be measuring the size of text so that you can position your caret where you need to. I'm not exactly sure how you could do that. But if you figure that out, the rest is doable. Although it will really require tons of wheel-reinventing code.

Answer (score 0):

Reminds me of a little experiment I did sometime back... I basically tried to create a primitive editor by simply listening to keypresses on a DIV and to insert them into the DIV as a new node. So imagine, each character would be wrapped in a  tag! It actually worked. But, once it reaches a couple of paragraphs, node insertion and deletion becomes rather slow. You will type a character, and it would only appear after a slight delay, and this simply unacceptable, and eventually I just gave up. Anyway it was just a random thing I wanted to try out..

Coming back to your question, I wonder if this can be replicated in JS alone as frankly the flash has superior raw processing power compared to JS. Even if it's technically feasible, I doubt whether it will be fast enough to actually work well. My two cents!

Comment: You should try it in Google Chrome, where the javascript is compiled to x86 machine code!

Answer (score 0):

[Atwood's Law](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/08/all-programming-is-web-programming.html):

> Any application that can be written in JavaScript, will eventually be
>   written in JavaScript.